# Apple Developer account error: Maximum number of certificates generated (development)

Tags: ios, apple-developer

What do I need to do to add a new developer certificate?

In an Apple Developer account I want to create a new Development certificate.

But I get the error: "**Maximum number of certificates generated**".

Previously I had 10 development certificates and want to add one more.

I deleted:

- 4 old development certificates (now there are 6 active development
  certificates);
- 2 production certificates (now there is 1 active production certificate);
- old app IDs;
- old devices;
- old keys.

Also, all of provision profiles (both development and distribution) have active status.

But I still get this error.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I have also run into this issue in the past. From my experience, it restores "empty slots" after 24 hours. If you still have this issue later than that, you may consider contacting Apple support.

Comment: I have been waiting for 7 days, but the result remains the same.

Comment: Regenerate all of your provisioning profiles to ensure the ones that are stored on their system don't still reference the deleted certificates. If that doesn't work, I still recommend contacting Apple support.

Comment: Rechecked, in provision profiles, the references are only for 6 active development certificates. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: The references that _show_ will only be the active ones. However, because you didn't regenerate the provisioning profiles after you deleted certificates, those are still technically _within_ them.

Comment: Absolutely all profiles were re-generated, and only the necessary certificates were indicated.

Comment: From Apple Forum:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/77131

For the distribution of in-house enterprise apps you may have two active certificates at any given time. Normally you will only use one at a time and then transition to the second certificate before the first one expires in three years.
 
One certifiate can sign any number of provisioning profiles which are what you need to run the app on devices.
 
Distribution Certificate: Program wide
Provisioning Profile: Per app

Comment: The question is about Development certificate, not Production.

Answer (score 5):

I **removed** unnecessary **Certificates**, **Provisioning Profiles**, and **Identifiers** on **developer.apple.com**. After removing them it worked successfully.

Please be careful about remove&revoke them. They are **irrevocable**.

Answer (score 2):

Since I had this problem and wasted time trying to find the problem, the solution for next friends should be as follows.

Deleted certificates do not seem to have been deleted because they do not make any requests to apple side. If you open xcode and select Automatically manage signing, your certificates will be updated and you will be notified that they have been deleted.

If it still doesn't work, you can try to make a manual request by selecting the certificate you deleted from the profile section.

If that doesn't work, I would suggest contacting Apple support anyway